# Editing a file on Sharepoint via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, save

I'm trying to edit an Excel a file on SharePoint via VBA. I have a primary file (limited access) from which I need to copy data to another file (public access) when the master file is updated. I'm using Workbook_Deactivate to call the macro below. The intent is to copy the first five columns from the primary file to the public one.

```
Sub CopyMetaData()
'
' CopyMetaData Macro
'
Dim thisFile, dFilename, dFile, dPath As String

'
' Set File Parameters

thisFile = ThisWorkbook.Name
dFilename = "Metadata.xlsx"
dPath = "https://zzz.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/sites/path/to/folder"
dFile = dPath + "/" + dFilename

' Copy Metadata columns
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.Copy

' Open Destination File
Workbooks.Open Filename:=dFile, ReadOnly:=False
If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then
    MsgBox ("Read Only") 'for testing purposes
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadWrite
End If
' ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile  'Edit Mode did not work
Windows(dFilename).Activate
Range("A1").Select
'Paste to destination file, save and close
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

The problem I run into is that when I close and save the file, it still considers the file read-only. It pops up the Save As dialog, but I can actually save it using the same name if put that in. I just can't get it to save programmatically.

Comment: you can turn off the dialog box so the save will overwrite automatically. You could try something like Application.DisplayAlerts= False  dFileName.SaveAs dFile, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges   dFileName.Close Application.DisplayAlerts= True

Comment: Thanks Chris. Unfortunately, I'm still getting a "We can't save <file location> because the file is read only." I can't seem to get it out of read only mode. It works ok with a local file and it works with a file on Teams. But for some reason it's not working in SharePoint (even though I believe SharePoint is the "file system" for Teams).